# Supplying output parameter to sqlparametercollection resulting in error (Varbinary)

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

I want to supply an  output parameter to my stored proc. This output proc is returning `byte[]`. How do I do this?

If I do the following:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary));
command.Parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Byte[][1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0. This stored proc works fine in SQL Server when I execute it via the SSMS option "Execute Stored Procedure).
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a value to the Size parameter:

```
 new SqlParameter("@Bytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not know the return size then use -1, e.g.

```
New SqlParameter("@PreviewImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary) With {.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, .Size = -1}
```

This will then return any size.